# Zeus doesn't start on Rails 4.1 Ruby 2.1.1 setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeus

Here is my abbreviated setup:

```
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
rails (4.1.0.rc1)
rvm 1.25.22
zeus (0.13.3)
```

Whenever I run "zeus start" I get a full crash:

```
boot
└── default_bundle
    ├── test_environment
│   └── test_helper
└── development_environment
    └── prerake

Available Commands: [waiting] [crashed] [ready]
zeus test (alias: rspec) [run to see backtrace]
zeus server (alias: s) [run to see backtrace]
zeus console (alias: c) [run to see backtrace]
zeus rake [run to see backtrace]
```

And running "zeus s" afterwards gives this:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/parser.rb:33:in
   `<class:Parser>': superclass mismatch for class Mark (TypeError)
```

Comment: Not a real solution, but I had problems with Zeus and Rails 4, too. I finally switched to Spring, which is now the default in Rails 4.1, works fine for me and should be supported very well in the future. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#spring-application-preloader

Comment: Thanks just a quick sub-question, does this path look normal to you?

ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0

Comment: When I grep Psych in my RVM directory I get a similar path: `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/parser.rb`. So nothing unusual here...

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me also, mistake was that default gemset was not set in rvm for project folder. If you use rvm never forget to do `rvm use rubyversion@gemset` in project folder. Simple way to detect is this the problem is to check if `zeus start` runs ok in your current terminal and fails when run in new terminal. If this is the case just run rvm use in project folder.

Comment: Expand on this a bit more.  How do you set the default gemset in rvm?

Comment: you go to the project folder (from where you run zeus) and do: `rvm use rubyversion@gemset --default`, it should do even without --default

Comment: you should edit your answer with what you just wrote in the comments